# DOM Element Prototytpe

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I was creating my own widget:

```
Button = function(){};
Button.prototype = document.createElement('INPUT');

btn = new Button();
btn.type = 'BUTTON';
btn.value = 'test';
btn.onclick = function(){alert('TEST!')}
document.body.appendChild(btn);
```

This runs perfectly fine if I just open a new tab and  copy and paste into Firefox's console. But when I put them in a js file (wrapped in `$(document).ready`) and link it in the HTML, then open the HTML in browser, it failed.

On the `btn.onclick` line, it tells me:

```
uncaught exception: [Exception... "Illegal operation on WrappedNative prototype object"  nsresult: "0x8057000c (NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_OP_ON_WN_PROTO)"  location: "JS frame :: main.js :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 12"  data: no]
```

I kinda understand the error because I inherited the prototype, but I `new-ed` the element (not directly acting on it), and it runs ok in the console. Can anyone point out the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create DOM Nodes like this (and you're not prototyping correctly anyway, you'd need to use `HTMLInputElement.prototype` but that's another matter), instead do

```
Button = function(){
    var btn = document.createElement('INPUT');
    btn.type = 'BUTTON';
    return btn;
};
```

You can still do `new Button` except this time it will work as expected.

---

Edit: If you want to use `Button.prototype` to define properties and methods, you can copy them to `btn` in the constructor (this will be *ByVal* not *ByRef*)

```
for (i in Button.prototype) { // make sure to var i
    btn[i] = Button.prototype[i];
}
```

Try it with a prototype such as the following, but note that changes to `Button.prototype` won't be reflected in already created `btn`s.

```
Button.prototype = {test: function () {console.log('invoked');}}
```

Comment: … only `Button.prototype` properties do not work (as expected?)

Comment: @Bergi True, you'd have to attach them to `btn` before the `return` and depending how this is done they might not update with changes to `Button.prototype` in future. I've never seen a browser allow an object to be appended to a document that wasn't in some way the result of `document.createElement` though, so unless you know how..

Comment: I used `new Button()` and just `Button()`, they seems to both work. And I also tried to set `Button.prototype = {test: function(){alert("")}}` and use `new Button()` and use `btn.test`, but does not seem to work... why?

Comment: And I thought prototyping is correct? I saw this tutorial : http://phrogz.net/JS/classes/OOPinJS2.html they say I should set my prototype to be a new instance of the class (which is an object?)

Comment: Best way to prototype is without using instances but instead an object `Object.create(proto, propertyDefinitions)`, but that isn't the issue here; the issue is you want to put the new node into the `document` but because the object isn't constructed by native methods you'll get loads of errors when trying to append it. You either have to have the node as a property (danger of circular referencing confusing GC) or map properties from your proto to `btn` in `Button`

Answer (score 2):

I get the error whether I'm working in Firefox's developer console or not (on the `btn.type = ...` line).

In general, it's not guaranteed that [*host objects*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.8) will work correctly as prototypes. From [§8.6.2 of the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2):

> All objects have an internal property called `[[Prototype]]`. The value of this property is either `null` or an object and is used for implementing inheritance. **Whether or not a native object can have a host object as its `[[Prototype]]` depends on the implementation.**

*(My emphasis)*

Apparently in this case, the implementation (Firefox's SpiderMonkey) doesn't like your doing that.

Instead of trying to use a host object as a prototype, your best bet is probably to do what Paul suggested in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14005497/157247). (Your `Button` constructor will work either with or without `new`, since the new object created by `new` is thrown away if the constructor function returns a different object.)